# Show the conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\theta, U_1, U_2,\ldots$ be independent and uniform on $(0,1)$. Let $X_i = 1$ if $U_i\le\theta$ ,$X_i=−1$, if  $ U_i >\theta$, and let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots+ X_n$. In words, we first pick $\theta$ according to the
uniform distribution and then flip a coin with probability θ of heads to generate a
random walk. Compute $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 1\mid X_1, \ldots,X_n).$

Let $i_1,\ldots,i_{n}\in \left\{-1,1\right\}$ and $N= \text{the cardinality of} \left\{1\le i\le n:X_i=1 \right\}$.$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=i_1,\ldots,X_n=i_n)=\theta^{N}(1-\theta)^{n-N},$$$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 1,X_1=i_1,\ldots,X_n=i_n)=\theta^{N+1}(1-\theta)^{n-N},$$ $$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 1\mid X_1=i_1, \ldots,X_n=i_n)=\theta.$$

However, I have a sense that it may not be correct.

Comment: Shouldnt the first line be conditioned on $\theta$ since $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1=i_1,...,X_n=i_n)=1/2^n$?

Answer (score 2):

We have by the definition for conditional probability,

$$P(X_{n+1}|X_n,\ldots,X_1)=\frac{P(X_{n+1},\ldots,X_1)}{P(X_n,\ldots,X_1)}$$

and by the definitions for marginal probability and conditional independence,

$$P(X_k,\ldots,X_1)=\int_0^1\Big(\prod_{i=1}^kP(X_i|\theta)\Big)P(\theta)d\theta$$

can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is generated by the partition $\left\{\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{U_i\leqslant \theta\}^{\varepsilon_i},\varepsilon_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}$, where $A^1$ denotes $A$ and $A^0$ the complement of $A$. For $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_i)_{i=1}^n\in\{0,1\}^n$, write $A_\varepsilon=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{U_i\leqslant \theta\}^{\varepsilon_i}$. Then by the formula giving the conditional expectation of a random variable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a partition, one has
$$
\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=1\mid X_1,\dots,X_n)=\sum_{\varepsilon\in\{0,1\}^n}
\frac{\mathbb P\left( X_{n+1}=1\}\cap A_\varepsilon\right)}{\mathbb P(A_\varepsilon)}\mathbb 1_{A_\varepsilon}.
$$
In order to compute the involved probabilities, one can condition on $\theta$ and deduced that these terms depend only on the number of coordinates $i$ for which $\varepsilon_i=1$; we write $c(\varepsilon)$ this number. If $c(\varepsilon)=k$, then using the fomula

$$
\mathbb E\left[g(X,Y)\right]=\int \mathbb E\left[g(X,y)\right]d\mathbb P_{Y}(y),
$$
valid for independent random vectors $X$ and $Y$, one gets
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left( X_{n+1}=1\}\cap A_\varepsilon\right)&=\int_0^1\mathbb P\left( \{U_{n+1}\leqslant  t\}\cap \bigcap_{i=1}^k\{U_i\leqslant t\}\cap\bigcap_{i=k+1}^n \{U_i> t\}\right)dt\\
&=\int_0^1t^{k+1}(1-t)^{n-k}dt
\end{align}
and similarly, $\mathbb P(A_\varepsilon)=\int_0^1t^k(1-t)^{n-k}dt$. The formula mentioned by Gerard Letac allows to simplify the ratio $\mathbb P\left(\{ X_{n+1}=1\}\cap A_\varepsilon\right)/\mathbb P\left(   A_\varepsilon\right)$. Finally, letting $B_k:=\bigcup_{\varepsilon: c(\varepsilon)=k}A_\varepsilon$ gives an answer expressed as a linear combination of indicators of $B_k$.

Comment: But I think it maybe like this:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=1\mid X_1,...,X_n):=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=1\mid\sigma(X_1,...,X_n))$$$$=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathcal{I}_ \left\{X_{n+1\quad}=1 \right\}(X_{n+1})\mid \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)\right]$$$$=\mathbb{E}\left [ \mathcal{I}_ \left\{X_{n+1\quad}=1 \right\}(X_{n+1}) \right ]=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=1)=\mathbb{P}(U_{n+1}\le\theta)=\theta.a.s.$$Where have I made errors?

Comment: I agree with the first line (if $\mathcal{I}_ \left\{X_{n+1\quad}=1 \right\}(X_{n+1})$ is replaced by $\mathcal{I}_ \left\{X_{n+1\quad}=1 \right\} $ but in the second line, you seem to have used independence between the $X_i$, which does not hold. Moreover, the last equal sign is not correct: you have the probability  $\mathbb P(U \leq V)$, where $U$ and $V$ have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ hence the probability is $1/2$.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot ! I am sorry to say that I mistakenly took $\theta$ to be a constant.But why  $X_{n+1}$ is not independence with $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$?

Comment: You can have a look at $P(X_2=1,X_1=0)$ for example. $\{X_2=1\}$ and $\{X_1=1\}$ have both probability $1/2$.

Comment: Could you please clarify that $\mathbb P\left( X_{n+1}=1\}\cap A_\varepsilon\right)=\int_0^1\mathbb P\left( \{U_{n+1}\leqslant  t\}\cap \bigcap_{i=1}^k\{U_i\leqslant t\}\cap\bigcap_{i=k+1}^n \{U_i> t\}\right)dt ? $

Comment: @user250236 I have added a bit more details.

Comment: Perhaps a slight typo, $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1,X_2=0)$ should be $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1,X_2=1)$.Then $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1,X_2=1)=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{P}(U_1\le t)\cdot\mathbb{P}(U_2\le t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}t^2dt=1/3\ne1/4=\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_2=1).$Thanks for the additional hint you provided earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Of course your answer should not depend on $\theta.$ Actually with your good notations

$$\frac{\Pr(X_{n+1}=1, X_n=i_n,\ldots, X_1=i_1)}{\Pr( X_n=i_n,\ldots, X_1=i_1)}=\frac{\int_0^1\theta^{N+1}(1-\theta)^{n-N}d\theta}{\int_0^1\theta^{N}(1-\theta)^{n-N}d\theta}=\frac{N+1}{n+2}$$ using $$B(a,b)=\int_0^{1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx=
\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.$$